Discussion about Graham Priest's dialetheic views on Eastern and Western philosophy
Australian philosopher Graham Priest is famous for advocating Dialetheism, the view that there are true contradictions.  Dialetheism goes against the law of non-contradiction. This gives rise to the non classical logical systems which had much bigger popularity in India. One of them is known as catuṣkoṭi (lat. tetralemma). Tetralemma allows the statement to be true, false, both or neither. "Tetra" comes from these four options.
Classical Aristotelian logic claims that it is impossible for the latter two options to be true. This is expressed as law of non-contradiction (statement can't be both true and false) and law of excluded middle (statement is either true or false). Both are the essence of classical logic which heavily influenced Western philosophy. Kant, Wittgenstein and Heidegger all claimed to come towards contradictions in their work and all thought that their ideas hence must be incorrect or incoherent. While I'm not sure whether dialetheism holds a solution in their case, I'd like to refer to the case where I think it does hold. Namely, Mahāyāna Buddhism.
I agree with G. Priest that classical logic has its limits. It can't give answers to some philosophical questions.
Tetralemma is more encompassing logical system which can deal with questions classical logic can't. To draw the parallel with physics, classical logic bears the similar relationship to tetralemma as Newtonian theory of gravity bears towards the general theory of relativity.
I'd like to continue this discussion in the context of Mahāyāna Buddhism and how it relates to dialetheism.

One of the most important teachings in Mahāyāna is śūnyatā, (engl. emptiness). Emptiness is a metaphysical claim that phenomena lack real and substantial existence. They lack any nature by themselves and derive their identity by how they relate to other things. Their existence is only relative. Emptiness is thus tightly connected to another essential teaching in Buddhism, dependent origination (Sanskrit. Pratītyasamutpāda).
Nāgārjuna was a Buddhist philosopher who defended emptiness against some other philosophical schools in ancient India (Nyāya and Vaisheshika) and some interpretations of dharma (Buddhist thought) which saw some phenomena as having real existence.  His claim is that everything is empty including emptiness. This means that everything is dependently originated.
In Sangha (Buddhist community), one can often hear statements that ultimate reality is beyond concepts and can't be talked about. Definition of ultimate reality is given as a reality realised when all concepts are removed through the teaching of emptiness. The previous sentence is a statement that I'll argue is a true contradiction.
One can argue that the previous statement is false by pointing out that saying "something is beyond concepts" is itself a concept. If something is truly beyond concepts, we couldn't talk about it at all, and neither could we give any statements about it. This must include even saying that it's beyond concepts. However, the statement can be also regarded as true in the sense that we can't really say much about ultimate reality except that it's beyond concepts and descriptions. We need to let go of concepts to enter the ultimate:

In the case when the statement is verified as false, we're defining "ability to talk about ultimate reality" as an "ability to give any statements about it".

In the case when the statement is verified as true, we're defining "ability to talk about ultimate reality" as an "ability to give some statements about it (however limited they are)".


Therefore, the truth value of the statement depends on how "ability to talk about ultimate reality" is defined.
From the above arguments, we can conclude that ultimate reality can be talked about, in a limited way.

However, if we get back to the definition of the ultimate reality as "non-conceptual reality that is realised through emptiness", we have a problem. If we can talk about it, even in a limited way, we're still applying concepts to a reality that's non-conceptual by definition. We again come to the contradiction. How do we solve this? Kant, Heidegger and Wittgenstein didn't know.
Wittgenstein claims in the end of Tractatus that his work is meaningless as he gave statements about things he claimed can't be done. I'm not sure whether dialethism is really a solution in the case of Wittgenstein, but if one does agree with him, one is facing a contradiction. He concluded thus that Tractatus is meaningless.
I'll argue that this a bad move.
If Tractatus really were meaningless, than it can't establish anything and hence motivate the view that you can't give statements about some things (form, in his case). It's shooting oneself in the foot as Wittgeinstein's conclusion undermines the very idea he tries to make (that there are things one can't make statements about). In another words, if Tractatus is meaningless than Wittgenstein has no grounds to support his claim that statements can't be given about form.
Hence, if Tractatus were truly meaningless then it cannot motivate the view that it's meaningless.
This example shows how trying to avoid contradiction leads to incoherent conclusions.

Catuṣkoṭi provides a compelling, but counter-intuitive alternative, just accept contradiction. Some statements can be both true and false in the same sense.
Nāgārjuna used Catuṣkoṭi in his work which explains why he had much less problems with contradictions.
We conclude that "Ultimate reality is non-conceptual reality that's realised through emptiness" is a dialetheia, a true contradiction.
Nāgārjuna argued the same and came to the same conclusion.
My question: For people who are familiar with Graham Priest and his work, how do you see his views on Dialetheism?

,@MauroALLEGRANZA I think Dario wants to know what people think.

@kouty Yes, you're correct. Sorry, I've updated my question.

There are many readings of the Tractatus: most of them try to show that it is not meaningless, despite its face value.

@MauroALLEGRANZA I'd agree. Wittgenstein had a bit different view, though. If Wittgenstein is right and statements about form can't be made (which I don't think is true), one gets a dialetheia.

Modern math has techniques to deal with true or false in context using conventional logic. But also to deal with both true and false using fuzzy logic. Fuzzy logic combined with the concept of logical negation can also deal with not true and not false. There is also the concept of the empty set where the true or false attribute of some item can be no value assigned in the context. Conventional logic tries to determine the objective crisp meaning of true and false but the subjective evaluations of true and false in the context of human reasoning are uncertain, fuzzy, and crisp.

Yes but one thing is the Dialetheist formal logic and amother is to assert that what is not clear (that is 99% of all) is simply a third value and thus we have solved all puzzles of humanity.

Regarding Graham Priest's approach to Tractatus, see On Transcending the Limits of Language (2023).

@MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, I think my post also captures his view on Tractatus correctly.

@MauroALLEGRANZA Regarding Buddhist logic, I've studied Jan Westerhoff and Jay L. Garfield. I also read Nagarjuna a lot.

Honestly, his entire point is that the liar paradox is both true and false; ergo, the Law of noncontradiction is bad!  This just shows that he misunderstand the liar paradox completely.  Please refer to the Wikipedia article Liar paradox where you can find actual solutions to this.  Thus, we don't have to bite the bullet on "there are true contradictions in the world".
When you say "I agree with G. Priest that classical logic has its limits. It can't give answers to some philosophical questions", can you name a philosophical question that the Law of noncontradiction (LNC) cannot address?

For that, check my post. Buddhism is a good example. Also, if you agree with Wittgenstein that statement can't be given about form (which he claimed), you have a dialetheia.

Wittgenstein claims in the end of Tractatus that his work is meaningless as he gave statements about things he claimed can't be done. If one agrees with him, one also comes to towards the contradiction. Wittgenstein realised this and thus concluded that Tractatus is meaningless. I'll argue this is a very bad conclusion.
If Tractatus really were meaningless, than it can't establish anything and hence motivate the view that you can't give statements about some things (form, in his case).

Wittgenstein is shooting himself in the foot as his point undermines the very idea he tries to make (that there are things one can't make statements about). In another words, if Tractatus were really meaningless, than Wittgenstein has no grounds to support the claim that there are things one can't give statements about.
Hence, if Tractatus were truly meaningless than it can't motivate the view that it's meaningless. This shows how contradictions can be confusing and how trying to avoid them leads towards logically incoherent solutions.

Catuṣkoṭi, provides a compelling, but counter-intuitive alternative. Accept the contradiction.

@DarioMirić what thing about Buddhism LNC can't address? i'm not that familiar with Wittgenstein and don't know what "statement can't be given about form" really means, what form? form of what? and you said "if you agree" so i guess he tried to give some arguments then, all statements like "nothing can be said about thing-in-itself" and someone comes along and respond "but you just said something about it", these kind of debates are result of confusion and bad wording, they are not because of true contradiction

You can see where LNC and dharma don't agree in my main post. Argument is detailed.

Regarding confusion and bad wording, you'd need to be more concise as it's not sufficient to argue against dialetheism.

@DarioMirić here is an example if i say "nothing can be known" and you respond by saying "but isn't that knowledge itself?", i would say that the "nothing can be known" is an incomplete statement and you assumed that this statement captures your intention properly but it didn't, you probably meant "nothing can be known WITH THIS CONDITION", this is what i mean by "bad wording", it creates confusion

@DarioMirić "His claim is that everything is empty including emptiness." this kind of language is pretty similar to postmodern thinkers, for example derrida says "death to death" and people are writing 300 page "interpretation" of it, these people are just playing with words and this explains the confusion we see in young people regarding these matters

Can you address the dialethic statement, definiton of ultimate reality I gave in the main post? "Ultimate reality is a non-conceptual reality which is realised through emptiness."

We can talk about Wittgenstein as well, but you claim not being familiar with his work. Heidegger also encountered contradiction in his Seins und Zeit when he tries to answer the question of Being.

@DarioMirić "Ultimate reality is a non-conceptual reality" shouldn't you justify this definition? i would say "Ultimate reality can be known to some extend", it seems like you claim that it can't be known since it is "non-conceptual", then you should attack this sentence: "inside ultimate reality exist some sort of cognitive activity"

@DarioMirić It is unlikely Heidegger would entertain contradiction. Can you give an example?

@ChrisDegnen didn't Heidegger reject law of non contradiction? derrida was praising Heidegger for this

@ParsaFakhar There might be examples where Heidegger appears to state something contradictory, like being is nothing, but in this case it isn't meant as a rejection of non-contradiction. It's a matter of perspectives, as is the "both existent and non-existent" city of the Gandharvas in my answer, which raises the point that contradiction may be perspectival in Mahāyāna too.  Like the gateless gate, or highest perfect knowledge (that is no knowledge) Vagrakkhedikâ VII. They sound contradictory but are actually not.

@ChrisDegnen this is what i read, as far as i know Heidegger has a problem with LNC, https://philarchive.org/archive/SKETAN-2

@ParsaFakhar Looks like a good example for being wary of secondary literature. Skempton seems to be intent on seeing contradictions, even tying Heidegger's concept of inauthentic time to McTaggart's A series (p. 21) to do so.  This effort mainly depends on the coherence of McTaggart's notion of the unreality of time. (continues)

On page 19 Skempton writes "To ask what being is is to treat being as a “what,” an entity. ... Any talk of what transcends all whatness, all entities, involves paradox and self-contradiction." However, Heidegger clearly says "'Being' cannot be conceived as an entity; enti non additur aliqua natura" GA 2, H. 4 so there is no self-contradiction. Skempton has mistaken being for a being. (continues)

On page 41: "Heidegger claims that the objectifying “scientific” approach to entities rests on an observing consciousness whose way of thinking is bound by the principle of non-contradiction. Thus, for him, expressing what lies behind or beyond this realm of present-at-hand objects involves violating that principle." If whatever Skempton means by behind or beyond involves being I would note "Being comes to be experienced as ground/reason." The Principle of Reason (1956), p. 129.

Heidegger does note difficulty in clarifying the subject matter, but not contradiction. "In the course of pointing to the history of thinking as the Geschick of being, we constantly spoke of "being" and "ground/reason" because it was unavoidable. What these words say can never be drawn together and packaged in a definition. To intend to do such a thing would be to pretend to be able to smoothly and nonchalanty grasp all the essential determinations of "being" and "ground/reason," and of being able to do this in a representation that would hover above time." The Principle of Reason, p. 94.

@ChrisDegnen Heidegger's dominant question in his philosophy is the Seins Frage (question of Being). What makes something be? Heidegger argues that Being can't just be a being (an object), it's what makes objects be. Therefore, he argues that Seins Frage can't be answered nor asked because it treats Being as an object, just what it is not. He is facing a contradiction as he is saying plenty about what Being is in his Sein und Zeit.

@ChrisDegnen Of course, one may not agree with Heidegger that making statements about Being treats it as a being (an object). If one does, though, he is facing a contradiction.

@DarioMirić I see this as a matter of perspective again. Heidegger scopes out what Dasein is in terms of its relations to things, but then when one looks directly at it, it 'is' B̵e̵i̵n̵g̵. As if one could experience 'prior to' consciousness, obviously one would experience nothing, but then all one has to do is wake up and there it all is: all the relations of interactivity.

Even as an awake Dasein when one tries to think what underlies experience, i.e. what makes something be – it is encountered as nothing. In delineating these perspectives – toward conscious interactivity or the underlying foundation – reasoning depends on not mixing them up and thinking of them as the same and thus being contradictory.

Skempton makes an interesting point on page 21 that "The being-outside-oneself of ecstasy ... violate[s] a principle of non-contradiction that restricts thought to the presence of entities." But as soon as one moves 'outside oneself' existence follows. The intention may be to step into oblivion, but like one's shadow experience keeps up so there is no contradiction.

Incidentally, Derrida wrote a book titled Aporias – aporia definition: a logical impasse or contradiction. E.g. how can one be dead? It's interesting how he gets around it.

@ChrisDegnen If I understood you correctly, you argue that talking about Being doesn't make it a being. Therefore, you don't agree with Heidegger that talking about Being treats it as an object.

@DarioMirić I don't know where you get the idea that Heidegger says "that talking about Being treats it as an object", because Heidegger says in Being & Time, H. 4 that "'Being' cannot indeed be conceived as an entity", and he says that while talking about it.

@ChrisDegnen Yes, I think that statement could be a dialetheia. Check this paper: Speaking of the ineffable, East and West by Graham Priest. It discusses Mahāyana, Heidegger and Wittgenstein in the light of contradictions. You can find it online.

Derrida addresses the point directly in Heidegger: The Question of Being & History, p. 51-53, e.g. "the expression Sein is not only an infinitive but a verbal substantive ... It consolidates it and makes it into something. / Should we abandon a grammatical form that is so threatening for the right thinking of being, a thinking that is neither a concept nor a thinking of a being? Heidegger pretends to think so but only in order to show that simply renouncing this form, simply erasing this word that the verbal substantive is, would obscure the problem still further. ... What would happen if,

"giving up on the grammatical form of the verbal substantive in philosophical discourse, we had to limit ourselves to the other forms? ... In that case, one would say: being? — I know nothing about it. I do not know what that means, primarily because I’ve never come across it and no one will ever come across it. The pre-comprehension Heidegger talks about at the beginning of Sein und Zeit is in this case merely an incomprehension. I understand what being means only when being comes to determine something or is determined by something, when I say I am, and you are, and he or it is, and so on."

OP: We conclude that "Ultimate reality is non-conceptual reality that's realised through emptiness" is a dialethia, a true contradiction.
Ultimate reality.  Is this where Descartes' cogito comes from? or is this the reality beyond appearance, the thing-in-itself?
OP: Emptiness is a metaphysical claim that phenomena lack real and substantial existence.
The phenomena are mind-dependent appearances of things-in-themselves, of which the latter we know nothing.  They are to us as nothing, so the phenomena are empty.

It is like the city of the Gandharvas which the unwitting take to be a
real city though it is not so in fact.  The city appears as in a
vision owing to their attachment to the memory of a city preserved in
the mind as a seed; the city can thus be said to be both existent and
non-existent. (Lankavatara Sutra)


To the extent that physics studies the observable it therefore deals with phenomenal nature, while the unobserved is noumenal nature, of which we know nothing.
Perhaps Descartes' cogito could be considered to come from nature, but this might be an assertion too far for Heidegger.  Insofar as the cogito is a type of Being ...

Being and the structure of Being lie beyond every entity and every possible character which an entity may possess. (GA 2, H. 38, 1927)

So we can say very little about being.  In fact we are back to nothing again, rather like another noumenon.

The nothing is the "not" of beings, and is thus being, experienced from the perspective of beings. (1949 preface to On the Essence of Ground, Pathmarks, p. 97)

This does not seem to be a dialethic contradiction.  Just a consequence of perspectives.

OP: If we can talk about it, even in a limited way, we're still applying concepts to a reality that's non-conceptual by definition.
Seems rather like talking about a concept that is indefinable.

It has been maintained secondly that the concept of 'Being' is indefinable. (GA 2, H. 4)

But that is not a contradition either.

Ultimate reality understood in Buddhist terms doesn't have much to do with cogito. Ultimate reality comes from conventional reality when one understands that all phenomena lack real existence, they have only conditioned existence and are nothing in themselves. This is emptiness, one of the most important teachings in Buddhism and I think correct metaphysical nature of reality. One who understands it, doesn't cling to the phenomena and reaches Nirvana. I can't write much here. I'd prefer to write somewhere else.

There are a lot of things to say.

@DarioMirić If the cogito doesn't cogitate that is cessation; understanding that phenomena are empty spares cogitation. Boom :-)

The clear answer is that the ultimate reality isnt beyond concepts, and the definition simply doesnt hold. Ultimately Priest and all dialetheists have a serious semantical problem in their hands, which is the problem of destroying the sense of negation. Namely, contradictions by definition cannot be true since contradictions are basically conjunctions of contradictory terms, and contradictory terms are literally defined as terms which cant be both true (nor both false), which ironically entails that dialetheism actually supports the law of non-contradiction. However, as one can obviously know, dialetheism also opposes the law of non-contradiction. So what is the solution? It's simple: it is just one more contradiction for the dialetheist that the LNC and dialetheism both hold. And this "solution" makes dialetheism nonsensical, as even its negation properly loses the sense of a negation. This is the problem pointed out by Arenhart in his critique of the dialetheist solution to the liar paradox. About catuskoti, i feel like denying the law of excluded-middle should really make catuskoti just an arbitrary limitation. P is both true and false, or true and only true, or false and only false, or neither true nor false. Why not posit that P is not neither true nor false nor both true and false, nor true and only true or false and only false? If truth and falsity arent the only options then catuskoti (like literally any attempt to pinpoint truth values) is absurd and simply too limited. Either u accept that truth and falsity are exhaustive or u will have to deny any attempt to pinpoint truth values.

The problem is that ultimate reality is, by definition, non-conceptual.  Summary is given:
As you noted

Statement is false in sense that we can say that it's non-conceptual. If it were truly non-conceptual, we couldn't say anything about it, including that's non-conceptual

However,

Statement is true in sense that we can't say much about it except that it's beyond concepts. Truth value of the statement depends on how "non-conceptual" or "ability to talk about it" is defined.


In the case when the statement is verified as false, we're defining "non-conceptual" as an ability to give any statements about it.
In the case when the statement is verified as true, we're defining "non-conceptual" as an ability to give some statements about it (however limited they are).
From these arguments, we can conclude that ultimate reality can be talked about, in a limited way.
However, there is a problem here.

Ultimate reality is realised through teaching of emptiness, which is to let go of concepts.
Saying that ultimate reality is beyond concepts and that we need to let go of concepts to realise it is itself a concept.
We come towards the contradiction.
Some argue that the statement: "Ultimate reality is non-conceptual and realised through emptiness" can't be prescribed truth value (and hence it's not true, false or anything else) because it's meaningless. Why is it meaningless? Because we're talking about something which by definition can't be talked about.

If we come towards this conclusion, we have a problem.
Why? Because even the previous statement is a conceptual reference towards the ultimate reality. In another words, statement: "Ultimate reality is non-conceptual" is meaningless because we're talking about it, is self-refuting. It's shooting oneself in the foot as this statement also talks about the ultimate.
Therefore, we're losing the ground to support the concerned statement which also becomes meaningless. If it's meaningless, it can't establish that the statement: "Ultimate reality is non-conceptual" is meaningless.

It's very similar to Wittgenstein's Tractatus and Heiddeger's Seins Frage.
